# Solving for n - modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The question is as follows:

[image]

So I started by attempting to calculate 12^100 mod 47 by modular exponentiation, which if I'm not mistaken, turned out to be:

12^64 * 12^16 * 12^16 * 12^4 (mod 47) = 37 * 28 * 28 * 9 (mod 47) = 34.

So the original expression becomes 34n + 45! = 13 mod 47.

Then, I attempted to work out 45! mod 47 using Wilson's Theorem:

46! = -1 mod47.

I am unsure where to go from here. Would it be correct to divide by 46 to get 45! = -1/46 mod 47?

Comment: The first two dupes show how to compute the factorial and power, and the third shows how to solve the resulting linear congruence. In the first with $h=1$ we get $(p-2)! \equiv 1\pmod p,\,$ which is also easy to prove directly using $p-1\equiv -1$ in Wilson's formula.